# C++ Sorting characters rather than entire strings

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```
void selectionSort(string [], int);
void showArray(string [], int);

int main()
{
   const int SIZE = 20;

   string name[SIZE] = 
   {"Collins, Bill",  "Smith, Bart",  "Michalski, Joe", "Griffin, Jim",
    "Sanchez, Manny", "Rubin, Sarah", "Taylor, Tyrone", "Johnson, Jill", 
    "Allison, Jeff",  "Moreno, Juan", "Wolfe, Bill",    "Whitman, Jean",
    "Moretti, Bella", "Wu, Hong",     "Patel, Renee",   "Harrison, Rose",
    "Smith, Cathy",   "Conroy, Pat",  "Kelly, Sean",    "Holland, Beth"};

    // Show initial order
    cout << "The unsorted values are\n";
    showArray(name, SIZE);

    // Sort the strings
    selectionSort(name, SIZE);

    // Show ordered order
    cout << "The sorted values are\n";
    showArray(name, SIZE);



    return 0;
}




    void selectionSort(string name[], int size)
    {
        char startScan, minIndex, minValue;

        for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
        {
            minIndex = startScan;
            minValue = name[startScan].at(0);
            for(int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
            {
                if (name[index].at(0) < minValue)
                {
                    minValue = name[index].at(0);
                    minIndex = index;
                }
            }
            name[minIndex] = name[startScan];
            name[startScan].at(0) = minValue;
        }
    }


    void showArray(string name[], int size)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
            cout << name[count] << endl;
            cout << endl;
    }
```

I would like this program to display the unsorted array of strings, sort the strings, the display the sorted array. Instead it is only sorting the first letter of the names. Like so:

`The unsorted values are
Collins, Bill
Smith, Bart
Michalski, Joe
Griffin, Jim
Sanchez, Manny
Rubin, Sarah
Taylor, Tyrone
Johnson, Jill
Allison, Jeff
Moreno, Juan
Wolfe, Bill
Whitman, Jean
Moretti, Bella
Wu, Hong
Patel, Renee
Harrison, Rose
Smith, Cathy
Conroy, Pat
Kelly, Sean
Holland, Beth`

`The sorted values are
Aollins, Bill
Cmith, Bart
Cichalski, Joe
Griffin, Jim
Hanchez, Manny
Hubin, Sarah
Jaylor, Tyrone
Kaylor, Tyrone
Mmith, Bart
Mmith, Bart
Molfe, Bill
Phitman, Jean
Rmith, Bart
Su, Hong
Shitman, Jean
Su, Hong
Thitman, Jean
Wolfe, Bill
Whitman, Jean
Wu, Hong`

I feel like I'm close... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK to write such code if you are learning algorithms.

However note that in "real C++" (i.e. production code) we tend to:

- use STL containers instead of arrays
- use STL algorithms instead of raw loops

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    std::vector<std::string> names = 
    { 
        "Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Michalski, Joe", "Griffin, Jim",
        "Sanchez, Manny", "Rubin, Sarah", "Taylor, Tyrone", "Johnson, Jill",
        "Allison, Jeff", "Moreno, Juan", "Wolfe, Bill", "Whitman, Jean",
        "Moretti, Bella", "Wu, Hong", "Patel, Renee", "Harrison, Rose",
        "Smith, Cathy", "Conroy, Pat", "Kelly, Sean", "Holland, Beth" 
    };

    std::sort(names.begin(), names.end(), std::less<>());

    std::copy(names.begin(), names.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

}
```

Links:

- [Containers library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)
- [Algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)
- [Why should I use container classes rather than simple arrays?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html)
- [Scott Meyers: STL Algorithms vs. Hand-Written Loops](http://www.drdobbs.com/stl-algorithms-vs-hand-written-loops/184401446)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I am always curious about this concept and I think it slows my comprehension significantly. I rack my brain to come up with these solutions, then I browse the web and see code that looks NOTHING like mine. I mean, it makes sense in the same way learning proofs in math makes sense, it's just frustrating. I feel like I'm learning bad habits sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `selectionSort` you need to get rid of the three calls to `.at(0)`

when you write `name[startScan].at(0)`, the varible `name` is an array of strings, so `name[startScan]` is a string, so `name[startScan].at(0)` is the first letter of that string.

You need to compare by and assign by strings, not by chars. Getting rid of the `.at(0)`'s will do that, tho it will leave you with type errors, needing a few adjustments, and thus        `char startScan, minIndex, minValue;` should be

```
int startScan,minIndex;
string minValue;
```

Comment: I did that, now I get 
`Ch9_06.cpp: In function ‘void selectionSort(std::string*, int)’:`
`Ch9_06.cpp:52: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char’ in assignment`
`Ch9_06.cpp:57: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char’ in assignment`

Comment: you did all of it? or just the at(0) part?

Comment: You're my new best friend. I did just the at(0) first. So strings can be directly compared? I was under the impression I would have to compare them char by char..

Comment: c++ style std::strings are comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::sort with customized compare function

1. use std::vector to hold the Names array
2. define a customized compare function

   ```
   bool myCompare(string i,string j) 
   { 
           if(i.length() >= 1 &&
               j.length() >=1)
           {
               return (i[0]<j[0]); 
           }

           return false;
   }
   ```
3. use std::sort

   ```
   std::sort (vecName.begin(), vecName.end(), myCompare);
   ```

Comment: tsk, even is sort were acceptable, you dont need vector or a comparison function to use it,  `sort(name,name+SIZE);` would work just fine.

Comment: That's right for this case, but comparison function can work for many other complicated cases.